# How can i get the number of the place in an array (AS3)?

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-3

if I have an array like this:

```
var myArray:Array = ["apple","orange","strawberry"];
```

then I want to get the order number of the orange, which is 1, out. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the index of "orange" you could do this:

```
trace(myArray.indexOf("orange")); // returns 1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get a hold of data in a few different ways it might be worth using a dictionary object.

http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/07/as3_dictionary_.html

Answer (score 2):

Refer the following link, then will know about all feature of arrays.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Array.html